# CRUD operations in fastapi are giving validation error

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, fastapi

this is fastapi with boto3 dynamodb , both new to me . I get :1 validation error for Request body field required (type=value_error.missing).

```
import boto3
# from pydantic.main import BaseModel
import jsons
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List, Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI,Query,Request,status,HTTPException
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError
from fastapi.responses import PlainTextResponse
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key,Attr
# from fastapi.routing import APIRoute, APIRouter
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse



app = FastAPI()

origins = ["*"]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
class ItemDoctor(BaseModel):
    ID:str
    Doctor:str
    Phone:Optional[str] = Query(None, max_length=10, min_length=10)
    Email:str
    Password:str
    Gender:str
    Age:str
    Experience:str
    Designation:str
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

class ItemPatient(BaseModel):
    ID:str
    Patient:str
    Phone:Optional[str] = Query(None, max_length=10, min_length=10)
    Email:str
    Password:str
    Gender:str
    Age:str
    Complaints:str
    Previous_Ailments:str
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


TABLE_NAME="resultTable"

# Creating the DynamoDB Client
dynamodb_client = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name="ap-south-1",
                                        aws_access_key_id="AKIAWHB3NDZVSH6FQQ4I",
                                        aws_secret_access_key="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"
                                 )

# Creating the DynamoDB Table Resource
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name="ap-south-1")
table = dynamodb.Table(TABLE_NAME)

@app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
async def validation_exception_handler(request, exc):
    return PlainTextResponse(str(exc), status_code=400)


@app.get('/{Patient}',status_code=200)
def Records(Patient:str):
    response = table.scan(
                        TableName=TABLE_NAME,
                        #KeyConditionExpression=Key("").eq("1"),
                        FilterExpression=Attr("Patient").eq(Patient)
                        )
    if not Patient:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,detail=f'Patient with name {Patient} is not available')
    items = response['Items']
    print(items)
    return items




@app.get('/all/',status_code=200)
def AllRecords():
    response = table.scan(TableName=TABLE_NAME)
    data = response['Items']
    while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
        response = table.scan(ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey'])
        data.extend(response['Items']) 
    return data



TABLE_NAME2="Doctor"
# Creating the DynamoDB Table Resource
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb',region_name="ap-south-1")
table = dynamodb.Table(TABLE_NAME2)



@app.put("/personaldetails/adddoctor",status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
async def create_item(item:ItemDoctor):

    table = dynamodb.Table('Doctor')

    table.put_item(
    Item={
            'ID':item.ID,
            'Doctor':item.Doctor,
            'Phone':item.Phone,
            'Email':item.Email,
            'Password':item.Password,
            'Gender':item.Gender,
            'Age':item.Age,
            'Experience':item.Experience,
            'Designation':item.Designation
    }
    )       
    return 
    
@app.get('/personaldetails/{DoctorName}',status_code=200)
def Record(DoctorName:str):
  
    respons2 = table.scan(
                        TableName=TABLE_NAME2,
                        #KeyConditionExpression=Key("").eq("1"),
                        FilterExpression=Attr("DoctorName").eq(DoctorName)
                        )
    if not DoctorName:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,detail=f'Patient with name {DoctorName} is not available')
    item = respons2['Items']
    print(item)
    return item


TABLE_NAME3="Patient"
# Creating the DynamoDB Table Resource
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name="ap-south-1")
table = dynamodb.Table(TABLE_NAME3)


@app.put('/personaldetails/addpatient/',status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
def EnterRecord2(items:ItemPatient):
    table = dynamodb.Table('Patient')
    response = table.put_item(
       Item={
            'ID':items.ID,
            'PatientN':items.Patient,
            'Phone':items.Phone,
            'Email':items.Email,
            'Password':items.Password,
            'Gender':items.Gender,
            'Age':items.Age,
            'Complaints':items.Complaints,
            'Previous_Ailments':items.Previous_Ailments

            }
    )
    
    return "Data added successfully"



@app.get('/personaldetails/{PatientName}/')
def Record2(PatientName:str):
  
    respons2 = table.scan(
                        TableName=TABLE_NAME3,
                        #KeyConditionExpression=Key("").eq("1"),
                        FilterExpression=Attr("PatientName").eq(PatientName)
                        )
    if not PatientName:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,detail=f'Patient with name {PatientName} is not available')
    item2 = respons2['Items']
    print(item2)
    return item2
```

I tried it in postman. so i get this error

Answer (score 1):

You can't define `Query` parameters within a Pydantic model. They have to be independently defined as arguments to your endpoint function. There are other ways to do it using dataclasses but not with Pydantic models.

Since there is no info on the exact query you're sending in from Postman, I'm going to assume you are passing the field `Phone` from your models as a Query parameter like `/personaldetails/addpatient/?phone=1234567890`.

With your current setup FastAPI is expecting the `phone` parameter to be supplied in the JSON body with the rest of the model, and you're supplying it as a query parameter, so you're receiving a 422 error because it can't find that parameter. I'm not 100% certain what the behavior of `Optional` is in this context as you're not meant to use `Query` from within a Pydantic model.

To say definitively if that is your problem, we would need to see exactly what query you're sending in and what error you're receiving back.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the issue somehow....no problem with the code...just i wasn't sending any body in postman for my put method